# Rails simple_form grouped collection not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app, I'm using simple_form.

I'm trying to use grouped collection selects.

Without simple_form, this works:

```
<%= f.label :employee_id, "Lead3:" %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :employee_id, Workgroup.order(:id) , :employees, :group, :id, :employee_full_name %>
```

But, my simple_form attempt doesn't - the dropdown is empty:

```
<%= f.input :employee, collection: @workgroups, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employees, :label => 'Lead2:' %>
```

OR

```
 <%= f.association :employee, collection: @workgroups, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employees, :label => 'Lead2:' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check your `@workgroups` definition in the controller. It probably returns `nil` or is not specified. Depending on what action calls your form, you should have something like this:

```
@workgroups = Workgroup.all(order: id)
```

Comment: I changed the controller to @workgroup = Workgroup.order(:id) - and get the same results.

Comment: I had a research for a half an hour , it seems the best way to populate the items of `association` input is: `<%= f.association :employee, collection: Workgroup.all(:order => :id), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employees, :label => 'Lead2:' %>` . Another question: do you associate models which have `has_and_belongs_to` each other?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm not using has_and_belongs_to.